# Using Arcpy.Mapping to add raster layers?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.3, layers

I am trying to add raster layers in specific data frames @current mxd. The script works in the ArcGIS 10.3 Python console but when I created a custom toolbox and add the script in the custom toolbox the script tool neither works nor gives an error.

Here is the script:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env


mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('Current')
workspace=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
dflist=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
listraster=arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in listraster:
    lyr=arcpy.mapping.Layer(raster)
    if str(lyr)=='om_in_percent':
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dflist[0],lyr)
    elif str(lyr)=='cec_status':
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dflist[1],lyr)
    elif str(lyr)=='n_inpercent':
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dflist[2],lyr)
    elif str(lyr)=='si_status':
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dflist[3],lyr)
    else:
        print(arcpy.GetMessage(1))
```

Any Help?

Comment: What was the error saying? Please edit your question to add the error message.

Comment: do you care introducing print from line 4, this would help in debugging..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a step to set the workspace to that provided by the input from the tool.

Try:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('Current')
workspace=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
dflist=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)

# Set workspace before listing rasters
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
listraster=arcpy.ListRasters()
#...
```

Comment: @Amsalu No problem! If you're happy that this has answered your question, would you mind accepting it by clicking the tick to the left.